# Entity Framework Count with a filter on field really slow - large count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

When I am running a Model Mapping, one company has a lot of members, like 405,000 members.

```
viewModel.EmployeeCount = company.MembershipUser.Count(x => x.Deleted == false);
```

When I run the SQL query, it takes a few milliseconds. In ASP.NET MVC, EF6 C# this can take up to 10 minutes for one list view controller hit. Thoughts?

Company is my Domain Model Entity, and MembershipUser is a public virtual virtual (FK) using entity framework 6, not C#6

When I'm in my CompanyController (MVC) and I ask for a company list, I get a list without the company count included. When I do a viewModelMapping to my Model to prep to pass to the view, I need to add the count, and do not have access to the context or DB, etc.

```
            // Redisplay list of companies
            var viewModel = CrmViewModelMapping.CompanyListToCompanyViewModel(pagedCompanyList);
```

CompanyListToCompanyViewModel maps the list of companies to the list of my ViewModel and does the count (MembershipUsers) there.

I also tried adding the count property to the company DomainModel such as:

```
public int EmployeeCount
    {
        get
        {
            // return MembershipUser.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).Count();
            return MembershipUser.Count(x => x.Deleted == false);
        }
    }
```

But it also takes a long time on companies with a lot of Employees.

It's almost like I want this to be my SQL Query:

```
Select *, (SELECT count(EmployeeID) as Count WHERE Employee.CompanyID = CompanyID) as employeeCount from Company
```

But early on I just assumed I could let EF lazy loading and subQueries do the work. but the overhead on large counts is killing me. On small datasets I see no real difference, but once the counts get large my site is unsusable.

Comment: What's `company`? Also, try to log what query is getting executed on the server. Notice that ASP.NET MVC 6 does not exist nor it will ever.

Comment: See what SQL is actually being issued. Perhaps, since this is a navigation property, and not a DbSet, all the users for the company is loaded from the server, and then counted in your application?

Try what happens if you go to the DbSet for MemberUser and do a `Count(x => x.CompanyId == company.Id && x.Deleted == false)`.

Comment: `When I run the SQL query` => The one generated by EF?

Comment: What is the type of MembershipUser property?

Comment: MembershipUser is fk connected Domain Model Entity, MembershipUser has a company_companyID key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are accessing the navigation property and using the count method, you are materializing all the `MembershipUser` table and doing the filter in C#.

There are three operations in this command: The C# go to the database and execute the query, transform the query result in C# object list (materialize) and execute the filter (x => x.Deleted == false) in this list.

To solve this problem you can do the filter in the MembershipUser DbSet:

```
Db.MembershipUser.Count(x => x.Deleted == false && companyId == company.Id);
```

Doing the query using the DbSet, the filter will be done in database without materialize all 405000 rows.

Comment: This make a lot of sense. And I see why this query goes off and does some work and comes back 10 minutes later. But I am not sure how to implement in code. When I'm on my controller (MVC) and I ask for a company list, I get a list without the company count included. When I do a viewModelMapping to my Model to prep to pass to the view, I need to add the count, and do not have access to the context or DB, etc.

Comment: @ransems, isn't the adding the context or db only a matter of including a namespace to the scope?

Comment: It's so far abstracted when I'm passing data from controller, using an IOC container, then passing to a viewModelMapping function which has no idea about db's or connections's or db's connections

Comment: It's almost Like i need my CompanyService (which does the db queries) to return the full company entity and have the counts of employees already included in the SQL query.

Comment: Maybe I can loop through each company at the CompanyService (my db access service) and 'add' a count, at least it only has to go to the db 25 (max page size) or so more times separately to get the count - but the count would be executed by SQL and not needing to materialize the 405000 entities connected.